# Duda con promedio en java

Tags: java, float

Buenas a todos, tengo una pequeña duda, al momento de realizar el promedio de edades(en este caso son 5 personas que ingresan sus edades) y se hace la operacion:

```
promedio de edad = suma total de edades / 5
```

Quiero que me salga 'al menos' con un decimal, osea :

**promedio de edad = (28+24+25+33+37)/5
                 = 29.4**

Sin embargo por mas que la variable 'promedio de edad' lo eh declarado como float, siempre me aparece asi: **29.0**

Dejo mi codigo aqui para que tengan mejor panorama de mi problema :(

```
 package trabajo_lab2_prom_edad;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Trabajo_Lab2_Prom_Edad {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int edad_hombre = 0;
    int edad_mujer = 0;

    float promedio1 = 0;
    float promedio2 = 0;

    int contenedor1 = 0;
    int contenedor2 = 0;

    int total = 0;

    Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);

    int contador_hombre = 1;

    while (contador_hombre <= 5) {

        System.out.println("Ingrese la edad del " + contador_hombre + " hombre ");
        edad_hombre = leer.nextInt();
        leer.nextLine();
        contador_hombre++; 
        total = total + edad_hombre;
        promedio1 =total/5;
    }

    System.out.println("suma total de edades hombre: " + total);

    System.out.println("El promedio de edad de hombres es de: " + promedio1 + "%" ); 



    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------//

    int contador_mujer = 1;

    while(contador_mujer <=5){
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Ingrese la edad de la " + contador_mujer + " mujer ");
        edad_mujer = leer.nextInt();
        leer.nextLine();

        contador_mujer++;
        total= total + edad_mujer;
        promedio2 = total/5;
        }

        System.out.println("suma total de edades mujer: " + total);
        System.out.println("El promedio de edad de mujeres es de: " + promedio2 + "%");
        leer.close();            

        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------");

        System.out.println("Suma de promedio de edades entre hombres y  mujeres: ");
       double totalprom;
        totalprom = promedio1 + promedio2;
        System.out.println(totalprom);
        System.out.println("Redondeo de ambos promedios: ");
       int i2 =  (int) totalprom;
        System.out.println(totalprom);


}
```

}

Comment: El error esta en el tipo de dato de las variables, total y edad_hombre son variables de tipo int..al menos una de ellas debe ser float.

Comment: porque declaras la edad_hombre , como entero? deberias declararla como float y tambien total.

Answer (score 0):

para lo que pides solo tienes que tener en "float" el promedio y el total, te muestro mi codigo para que veas como lo hice yo:

```
package promedio;

public class Promedio {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int edades[] = {7, 8, 7, 9, 6};
        int edad = 0;
        int contador = 0;
        float total = 0;
        float promedio = 0;

        while (contador < 5) {
            edad = edades[contador];
            contador++;
            total = (float) total + edad;
            promedio = total / 5;
        }
        System.out.println("Total: " + total);
        System.out.println("Promedio: " + promedio);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

mira el problema de tu código consiste en esto:

Aunque tu variable **promedio1** se declare como *float*, al ser tus varibles **total** y **edad_hombre** de tipo *int*, se esta descartando la parte fraccionaría del cociente antes de asignar el resultado de la división a **promedio1**. Ya que al dividir dos variables enteras se produce un resultado entero.

Para realizar un cálculo de punto flotante con valores enteros, se debe tratar temporalmente a estos valores como números de punto flotante para usarlos en el cálculo, es decir, necesitas agregar un **operador unario de conversión de tipo**.

Lo que te respondió iuninefrendor es correcto, sin embargo, no te explica por que sucede esto ni por que se debe hacer así. Como muestra en el código que escribio, la parte que debes corregir es esta:

promedio1 = (float) total / 5;

El cálculo ahora consiste en un valor de punto flotante (la copia float temporal de total) dividido entre el entero 5.

Agregando el (float) creas una copia de punto flotante temporal del operando total (que aparece a la derecha del operador). Utilizar un **operador de conversión de tipo** de esta forma es un proceso que se denomina **conversión explícita** o **conversión de tipos**. Sin embargo, el valor almacenado en la variable ***total*** sigue siendo un entero.